# Perform segue from navigation control to tab bar navigation swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

i am trying to perform segue from the last screen of navigation control (stack - where you can back) to the first screen of tab bar navigation. The only thing i success so far is to open the first screen of the tab bar without the bottom tabs and with back button on the top. any idea?

```
  func userLogin(status: Bool, user: UserModel) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if status == true{
            self.userModel = user
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.gotoOverview, sender: self)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register", message: "some message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! OverviewController
    vc.userModel = userModel
}
```

Comment: There is a View Debugger tool in Xcode 11 that can help you visualize the view hierarchy. When the app is running in the simulator, select Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy. What do you see and is it what you expected from the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

why you are doing with segue when you can done this work by set root view controller to the first view controller.

for ex:- at the end of the navigation screen you want to set first screen as a root view controller.

if your tabbar icon not appear then you can also create your tabbar vc identifer and set that controller as your current vc and it will work.

when you are on your last vc(View Controller) then use the navigation to push your vc.

```
     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = 
    storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: TabBarVC)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

[image: Create tabbar Controller class]

Comment: Hi Vipin i am a little bit new to ios swift can you please show some example or reference to article?